# FabActUtil.exe exits with code -1

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I'm getting the following error on all builds including Service Fabric packages now:

```
build\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.targets(34,5): 
error MSB3073: The command ""\Build\x64\Debug\\FabActUtil.exe"
/app:"\ApplicationPackageRoot" /spp:"PackageRoot" /t:manifest /ap:"Project"
/sp:"Project1" /in:"..\Build\x64\Debug\\Project1.Exe"
/local5nodeappparamfile:"ApplicationParameters\Local.5Node.xml" 
/local1nodeappparamfile:"ApplicationParameters\Local.1Node.xml" " 
exited with code -1.
```

Running on Service Fabric 5.2.207, SDK 2.2.207

What is code -1 for FabActUtil.exe and is there any way to get better error output on this event?

Comment: can you add the SDK version to the question?

Comment: Did, 5.2 & 2.2, I'm working on upgrading my solution to 5.3 - 2.3 now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Running the command from the error message outside of Visual Studio gave the following message with a stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been     
added. 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource 
resource) 
  at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, 
TValue value, Boolean add) 
  at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Generator.ManifestGenerator.Context.LoadExistingContents() 
  at Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.Generator.ManifestGenerator.Generate(Arguments arguments) 
  at FabActUtil.Tool.GenerateOutput(ToolContext context) 
  at FabActUtil.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

This was due to the `ApplicationManifest.xml` having a repeated definition for one of the default services.

Thanks to amanbha: https://github.com/amanbha

Comment: Will also add that upgrading to Service Fabric 5.3 fixed a lot of issues with FabActUtil tripping over itself when copying files and deleting itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you encountered to error of FabActUtil.exe using the Service Fabric SDK.
In case that when the MS Build intends to build service fabric actors using FabActUtil.exe with target file, and the error occurred that FabActUtil.exe exited with code -1. The error can be fixed by changing the target file. Most simple approach is use the target file of old Service Fabric SDK.

If your solution is running normal so far, I think you have some Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors package in the packages folder of your solution’s root.

If you don’t have any package running normal, use [this target file of Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.2.2.207](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors/). This file has [differences](http://blog.processtune.com/?p=3191) with the file which error occurs at the points that copy and run then delete FubActUtil.exe.

The target file is:

```
%solution root%\packages\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.%version%\build\Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.targets
```

and independent with versions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I removed bin folder from project which could not compile, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error.  In my case it was because I was overloading the Actor methods.
This is not allowed, unfortunately.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-create-your-first-linux-application-with-java

Overloading is a very essential aspect of coding, especially when using Command pattern..  Don't know why this is not supported in SF Actors..

Also, the error does not indicate the cause of the problem.  I had to do process of elimination in my code to figure it out